# Simple proof of uniqueness of Lebesgue Decomposition?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Lebesgue's Decomposition Thm** states: if $\lambda,\mu$ are $\sigma$-finite measures on a measurable space $(X,\textbf{X})$, then $\exists$ unique measures $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ on $(X,\textbf{X})$ s.t.

- $\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$

  $\lambda_1 \perp \mu$ (mutually orthogonal: $\exists A,B \in \textbf{X}$ that partitions X, and $\lambda_1(A)= \mu(B)=0$

  $\lambda_2 << \mu$ (abs cont: $E \in \textbf{X}, \mu(E)=0$ implies $ \lambda_2(E)=0$)

I have read Bartle's pf of this fact in his "Elements of Integration".  I'm comfortable with the existence part, but my question is about the uniqueness part. 
Bartle says it follows from the fact that if $\alpha$ is a measure s.t. $ \alpha \perp \mu$ and $\alpha << \mu$, then $\alpha$=0. 
[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515155/proving-uniqueness-in-lebesgue-decomposition) gives an answer that deals with signed measures, starting with finite measures and then extending to the $\sigma$-finite case, but I suspect there is an easier way since I don't feel Bartle would have "buried that much work" inside one sentence, given the nature of his previous proofs.  So I guess my question is if there's a way to avoid signed measures.
What I've tried so far is essentially in the link above.  Let (since we already have existence)

- $\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = \lambda_3 + \lambda_4$

  $\lambda_1, \lambda_3 \perp \mu$

  $\lambda_2,\lambda_4 << \mu$

I'm tempted to use $\alpha= \lambda_3 - \lambda_1$, but we don't know that this is a measure.

Comment: That's the right way to go. You can prove it's a measure by definition.

Comment: @QiyuWen No, you're missing a point. The difference of two (positive) measures need not be a signed measure, in fact it can be _undefined_. Because $\infty-\infty$ is undefined...

Comment: I doubt you're going to find a proof that's much simpler.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  is it what you meant :  Jason's easier way is not so easier because for making sense to $\alpha = \lambda_3 - \lambda_1$ we'll need the same idea of restriction to a sub $\sigma$-algebra where $\lambda_1,\lambda_3$ are finite measures ?

Comment: @user1952009 I didn't mean that exactly - he didn't say what his easier way was. _If_ we're going to derive the result by considering $\alpha=\lambda_3-\lambda_1$ then yes, it seems we need to start with finite measures. It seems to me he understands this. There _could_ be some totally different approach that _would_ be simpler. I doubt it (because the standard argument really isn't that complicated, for one thing).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for completion. In the setting of Lebesgue's decomposition I automatically assumed that $\lambda$ was a complex measure.

Comment: The lemma that $\alpha \bot \mu$ and $\alpha \ll \mu$ imply that $\alpha = 0$, does not hold when $\alpha$ is a signed measure.

Comment: I found a [proof](https://www.cmi.ac.in/~prateek/measure_theory/2010-11-01.pdf) that does not deal with signed measures (although the document still included the difference of measures).