# Another question about proving Lebesgue Decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Note:** This is my original question.  I have been kindly helped to turn this into a correct proof, which I have posted as an answer so this question won't show up as "unanswered".
As an exercise, I am trying to provide a rigorous proof of uniqueness in the Lebesgue Decomposition Thm, assuming we already have existence.  I am following the outline provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515155/proving-uniqueness-in-lebesgue-decomposition). Below is what I have so far 
**Step 1**: Assume $\lambda$ is a finite measure ($\mu$ only needs to be $\sigma$-finite).

- Let $$\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = \lambda_3 + \lambda_4, \text{where } \lambda_1, \lambda_3 \perp \mu \text{ and } \lambda_2,\lambda_4 \ll \mu \tag1$$

  Let $\alpha:=\lambda_3 -\lambda_1 =\lambda_2-\lambda_4$

  Extend defns of singular & abs cont to signed measures: (I just do the most intuitive thing here) $\alpha \perp \mu $ means $\exists$ a partition A,B of X s.t. $\alpha(A)= \mu(B)=0$.  $\alpha \ll \mu$ means $\mu(E)$=0 implies $\alpha(E)$=0.

  Show $\alpha \perp \mu$ and $\alpha \ll \mu$.  This is just checking defns.

  Conclude $\alpha$=0.  I'm stuck here.  By the previous pt, $\exists$ a partition A,B of X s.t. $\alpha(A)=\mu(B)$=0.  Further, $\mu(B)$=0 implies $\alpha(B)=0$.  So $\alpha(X)=\alpha(A)+\alpha(B)$=0.  But we may have a partition $X_1,X_2$ of X s.t. 0 $< \alpha(X_1)=-\alpha(X_2)$.

**Step 2**: (General case) $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite.

- Let $X_1 \subseteq X_2 \subseteq$..., $X=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$, each $\lambda(X_n)< \infty$.

  $\forall n$, $E \in \textbf{X}$, put $\lambda_n(E):=\lambda(E \cap X_n)$, which is a finite measure, so $\exists$ a unique Lebesgue decomp $\lambda_n=\lambda_{1n}+\lambda_{2n}$

  Assume (1) again.  Now I don't know how to show $\lambda_1=\lambda_3$.  I’m trying to use the previous bullet pt.  I think I can show $\lambda=(\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda_{1n})+ (\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda_{2n})$ is a Lebesgue Decomp, but how do I know there aren’t others?

Comment: Say $E$ is $\nu$-null if $\nu(F)=0$ for every $F\subset E$. For signed measures this is not the same as just $\nu(E)=0$. Go through your proof (including the definitions), and change "$\nu(E)=0$" to "$E$ is $\nu$-null" everywhere and see what happens. (One of the new definitions is equivalent to the old one, one is not.)

Comment: Previous comment is something you need to change to make it all work. This one doesn't really matter. But in Step 2 it might work out nicer if you took the $X_n$ to be disjoint instead of nested.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thx for your helpful comments (both here and on my previous question).  I see how to do the $\lambda$ is finite case now.

Comment: But you still have the wrong definitions in the new version! Saying $\alpha\perp\mu$ simply does _not_ mean what you say it does. You're trying to prove something false.

Comment: Hmm, a possible reason for the confusion: I say that you should say that $E$ is a $\nu$-null set if $\nu(F)=0$ for every $F\subset E$. This is equivalent to saying $|\nu|(E)=0$. But the notation $|\nu|$ can be confusing; $|\nu|(E)$ is _not_ $|\nu(E)|$. (So what _is_ $|\nu(E)|$? Look it up somewhere; it's the "total variation" measure of $\nu$. I didn't mention it because we don't really need it here; I'm mentioning it now because maybe it happened that you've seen these definitions phrased in terms of $|\nu|$; if you have the reasonable but wrong idea that $|\nu|(E)=|\nu(E)|$ this won't work.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich.  You're right, I originally had the correction at the bottom, but I think correcting the main part makes it easier on other people viewing the question.

Comment: I think you're right about that - fooled me in any case...

Comment: Do you happen to know Step 2?  I'm sorry to say I'm not seeing the uniqueness :(

Comment: Well, so far there's no evidence that you've tried doing as I suggested, taking the $X_n$ to be _disjoint_. Try it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying.  So in 1st bullet pt assume the $X_n$ are disjoint.  2nd bullet pt unchanged.  3rd bullet pt all I can show is $\lambda= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_{1n}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_{2n}$.  This is A Lebesgue Decomp, but how do I know it's THE Lebesgue Decomp?  For instance, there could be some other decomp constructed from a totally different method.

Comment: Say you have another decomposition. The "restriction" of that decomposition to $X_n$ is a decomposition of the "restriction" of $\lambda$ to $X_n$. So the restriction of the decomposition to $X_n$ is uniquely determined. Take $\sum_n$.

Comment: I think I finally got it.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I want to acknowledge David C. Ullrich's role in helping me reach this answer. 
**Step 1**: Assume $\lambda$ is a finite measure ($\mu$ only needs to be $\sigma$-finite).

- Let $$\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = \lambda_3 + \lambda_4, \text{where } \lambda_1, \lambda_3 \perp \mu \text{ and } \lambda_2,\lambda_4 \ll \mu \tag1$$

  Let $\alpha:=\lambda_3 -\lambda_1 =\lambda_2-\lambda_4$

  Extend defns of singular & abs cont to signed measures: $\alpha \perp \mu$ means $\exists$ partition A,B of X s.t. $\mu(B)$=0 and A is $\alpha$-null ($\alpha(E \cap A)$=0 $\forall E \in \textbf{X}$).  $\alpha \ll \mu$ means $\mu(E)$=0 implies $\alpha(E)$=0.

  Show $\alpha \perp \mu$ and $\alpha \ll \mu$.  This is just checking defns.

  Conclude $\alpha$=0.

**Step 2**: (General case) $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite.

- Let $X_n$ be disjoint, $X=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$, each $\lambda(X_n)< \infty$.

  $\forall n$, $E \in \textbf{X}$, put $\lambda_n(E):=\lambda(E \cap X_n)$, which is a finite measure, so $\exists$ a unique Lebesgue decomp $\lambda_n=\lambda_{1n}+\lambda_{2n}$

  Let $\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ be any Lebesgue decomp.  Then the measures $E \mapsto \lambda_1 (E \cap X_n)$, $E \mapsto \lambda_2 (E \cap X_n)$ are $\perp, \ll \mu$, resp.  So they form a Lebesgue decomp of $\lambda_n$, and by uniqueness, $\lambda_1 (E \cap X_n) = \lambda_{1n} (E)$ and same using $\lambda_2$ instead.

  $\forall E \in \textbf{X}$: $$\lambda_1 (E) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_1 (E \cap X_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_{1n} (E)$$ where 1st "=" is countable additivity.  This shows $\lambda_1$ is uniquely determined.  Again, same idea for $\lambda_2$.